# VNC connection issue on Debian with xfce

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, vnc, xfce

I am trying to setup remote access to my VPS running on Debian stretch from my Windows 7 laptop.
I installed vnc4server and xfce desktop and setup tunneling the VNC traffic through ssh using Putty on the client machine. After installation the connection was working fine, also if I disconnect and then reconnect. However, if I disconnect try to reconnect after some time, I only see black screen (not sure exactly after how much time, but at least it is reproducible after an hour, but not reproducible if I reconnect right away). If I restart the vnc server, it is working fine again.

Here is the contents of my ~/.vnc/xstartup:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &`
```

I would really appreciate an advice here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution to this, so I am posting it, in case anyone runs into the same. All I had to do was to install xfce4-power-manager and disable power management for the display that's being used.